# Force firefox to open pages in a specific tab using command line

Tags: command-line, firefox, browser-tabs, telephony

Here's the challenge: I developed Softphone Screenpop PHP App that takes caller id info and searches for a match in our db, also allows us to collect call statistics. Great for our management but it's driving our reps nuts.

We use Firefox here and when our softphone pops to the external page, every time it opens in a new tab, the girls quickly get 5-10 open and it becomes confusing.

Our softphone will also run command line. I wondering if there is a way to have a URL open in a certain tab. I don't want to disable target="blank" links etc, I also don't want to kill the tab the user is working on. Otherwise does anyone have any other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can set Firefox to open all external links in the same tab.

1. Enter `about:config` in the address bar
2. Click the confirmation button if shown
3. Filter for `browser.link.open_newwindow`
4. Double click
5. Set value to `1`
6. OK

More info [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow) and [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction)

Comment: will this kill target="_blank" anchors

Comment: @mikey1980 - read the second link, there's info regarding exactly that

Comment: I needed this as well and this works great! I'm using FF 42.0